# Getting type of index signature

Tags: typescript

Is it possible to create a type that can get the type part of the index signature? 
Example:

```
type Foo = { [id: string]: Date }

type IndexSignatureType<T> = ???

const bar: IndexSignatureType<Foo>; // has type Date
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can just use an index type query:

```
type Foo = { [id: string]: Date }    
const bar: Foo[string]; // is Date
```